# Force a MultiIndex to update after dropping rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to force a pandas MultiIndex to update in the same way a standard one does?  See below:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([1, np.nan, 3], columns=['A'], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> df
     A
a  1.0
b  NaN
c  3.0
>>> df.dropna()
     A
a  1.0
c  3.0
>>> df.index
Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')
>>> df.dropna().index
Index(['a', 'c'], dtype='object')
```

With a MultiIndex this doesn't happen.  `b` stays in the index.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([1, np.nan, 3, 4, np.nan, 6], columns=['A'], index=midx)
>>> df
       A
x a  1.0
  b  NaN
  c  3.0
y a  4.0
  b  NaN
  c  6.0
>>> df.dropna()
       A
x a  1.0
  c  3.0
y a  4.0
  c  6.0
>>> df.dropna().index
MultiIndex(levels=[['x', 'y'], ['a', 'b', 'c']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 0, 2]])
```

Is there anyway to force the index to update too?